# Run 7z on a remote machine over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, 7zip

I have two debian machines and I want to do a 7z decompression directly on a remote machine connected over ssh. I connected to the remote machine and tried to run the command

```
7z x -so myfile.7z
```

This returned an error saying command not found. However, I am certain 7z is installed on the remote machine. And if I log in to the remote machine locally (in the real machine), this commands works fine.

Is there anyway I can run this command remotely over a ssh session?

Comment: did u cd to the file location?

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse. After I logged in using ssh, I cd to that location and then tried to run the command.

Comment: try ,    '7za e myfile.7z'

Comment: got this .. "-bash: 7za: command not found".  Should I install something for this

Comment: run 'whereis 7za' in remote machine and tell me the  outcome

Comment: This is probably a simple path problem where it's set up on the remote machine differently than when you login locally. If you log on locally, and to `type -p 7z` it should show you the full path to the file. You can either append that path to the directory, or invoke it directly. `whereis 7z` might also get you the location if the whereis database is looking for files in that location also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remote system doesn't have 7zip installed, so .7z files wont be unzipped until you install 7zip
to install 7zip `sudo apt-get install p7zip`
then unzip with `7za e myfile.7z`

Comment: That seems unlikely. Because I could decompress it fine when I log in to the remote machine locally, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: if it was installed in the remote machine, when you run 'whereis 7za' it should be giving you something like "7za: /usr/bin/7za /usr/share/man/man1/7za.1.gz".